# Module doesn't load ./App.tsx in index.js in typescript?

Tags: typescript, react-native

I want to develop a React native app using typescript. I read the **[document](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2018/05/07/using-typescript-with-react-native)** and follow the steps. According to doc whenever I change `App.js` to `App.tsx`, An issue occurs to load the app.tsx file in the index.js.

**Error : The module ./App could not be found in index.js**

But whenever I change App.tsx to App.js it works fine.

[image]

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?

Comment: @もっくん , According to the doc of typescript, don't change the file index.js. You may be change index.tsx it keep same when it create new project.

Comment: I haven't change it, but still get the same error message. Will keep trying to find the cause, thanks for the reply.

Comment: @KiritModi - before you converted to ts did you build the project?

Answer (score 2):

1. Remove App.js file
2. Rename file *index.js* to ***index.ts***.
3. Restart server and execute command react-native run-android.